# ASP.NET MVC Strongly Typed Partial View, gives could not load type error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, partial-views, strongly-typed-view

I am attempting to create a strongly typed view with a "MVC View User Control" that is being rendered using Html.RenderPartial().  The top of my ascx file looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Collections.IEnumerable<string>>" %>
```

There is nothing else on this page, currently.

When I execute the app and load the page that renders this control, I get the following error:

```
 Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Collections.IEnumerable<string>>'.
```

So, then I simplified it:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<String>" %>
```

And then, just in case it needed to be fully qualified:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.String>" %>
```

Everytime I get the same error (substituting type).  what am I doing wrong here? I'm on .NET 3.5 with ASP.NET MVC 1.0 RTM.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I got it working.  I followed the instructions from http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/04/05/could-not-load-type-systemwebmvcviewpage/ and that did the trick for me.  I should note that I also upgraded to the ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RC as of 3/17/2010 first.  The problem persisted for me still until I followed the instructions on that page.  I'm not sure if a fresh MVC project does this for you now or not.

The solution, in case the referenced page goes away, was to add a Web.config to my Views directory, and put this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" verb="*"
      type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
  </httpHandlers>

<!--
    Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
    after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
    MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
    To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
    controller or action.
-->
<pages
    validateRequest="false"
    pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
</pages>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
    <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I should also note that for MVC 2.0 you need to update the version #'s in the config.

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot to copy over my view folder web.config. I wish the error made it more obvious that this is what is wrong.

Comment: Wow, same problem here.  I had the web.config - worked on my machine - wasn't part of my build script.

Comment: I just created an MVC2 app and copied the web.config from that Views directory.  Thanks.